# How to convert struct tm to time_t by zeroing the hours ex: 00:00

Tags: c, date, datetime, time, time.h

```
struct tm t;
mktime(&t)
```

this returns something like `1199246400` -> `Tue Jan 1 02:00:00 2008`

but I need to get this back `1199160000` -> `Tue Jan 1 00:00:00 2008` (it's midnight)

If I always returned `1199160000` -> `Tue Jan 1 00:00:00 2008`

I could use `mktime(&t) - 60 * 120`

More obviously tm_hour constantly changes

So I need it to always return `date + 00:00:00` regardless of tm_hour set in struct tm

Thank you in advance

Comment: return 1199160000 -> date + 00:00:00

Comment: Are you initializing the members of `t`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Do you need a struct tm that represents the start of the today?  (Midnight for yesterday?)  Or perhaps the time_t value for the same moment?

Comment: Can you just set `t.tm_hour = 0;`?

Comment: I need to return the time in seconds with the hours set at 00:00: **1199160000**, as if it were to round

Comment: Are you interested in rounding or in truncating?  And are you interested in local time or UTC (or some other time zone)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the Unix timestamp for midnight at the start of today in local time:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *lt = localtime(&now);
    lt->tm_hour = 0;
    lt->tm_min = 0;
    lt->tm_sec = 0;
    time_t midnight = mktime(lt);
    printf("%ld\n", (long)midnight);
    return 0;
}
```

Output (at 2018-10-11 10:43 -07:00):

```
1539241200
```

A random time conversion utility:

```
$ timestamp 1539241200
1539241200 = Thu Oct 11 00:00:00 2018
$
```

- If you didn't want midnight local time, but the current hour, don't zero `tm_hour`.
- If you want UTC, use `gmtime()` instead of `localtime()`.  If you want to round (`tm_hour >= 12` maps to midnight tomorrow rather than midnight today), you have to test what to set.  Note, though, that `mktime()` normalizes the values in `tm_year`, `tm_mon`, `tm_day`, `tm_hour`, `tm_min`, `tm_sec` — so you can simply use `lt->tm_day++;` to switch to tomorrow, and it will correctly convert even at a month's end (so it isn't very hard to round – you just have to code the condition: `if (lt->tm_hour >= 12) lt->tm_day++;` before setting `lt->tm_hour` to zero).
- If you want to process an arbitrary time, take the value as a command line argument (default to `time(0)` when no arguments are passed), convert to `time_t` (probably via `strtoll()` and a `long long` variable), and then pass that to a function that does the rest of the conversion and printing.

We can debate whether the formatting as `long` and cast to `long` is best; it might be better to use `long long` or even `intmax_t`.